# Revoke celery task queue based on task id

Tags: django, queue, celery

I have two button in Django View in which the first button starts a celery task. I want to stop the queue when i press the second button. Is it possible to stop the queue simply based on the task id?

Here is my code snippet. The first button calls this function where I have created task for individual request that I want to send. I have created a list that stores task ids and have saved the list in session

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def requestKeywordCelery(request):    
 if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":         
    allkeywords = ['keyword1','keywrod2','keyword3']
   
    if len(raw_keywords) > 0:
        for i,key in enumerate(raw_keywords):                 
            task = requestKeywordCeleryTask.delay(key)
            task_id = task.id
            curlist.append(task_id)                
          
    request.session['task_session'] =  curlist    
    request.session.modified = True   

            
 return JsonResponse({
  
    "html": allkeywords,
    "success": True,
}, status=200)
```

Also I have this second button from where I access the task id lists from sessions and try to revoke it.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')    
def requestKeywordCeleryReset(request):
cursess = request.session.get('task_session')
//retrieved task id
index = cursess.index(data.task_id)
final_index = cursess[index+1]    
   
//here i have revoked it
current_app.control.revoke(final_index, terminate=True)  

return JsonResponse({
   
    "success": True,
}, status=200)
```

Comment: Please Add some code and tell more about what have been tried so far.

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi I have added the code snippet.